# Flash Builder - How to design a UI with out MXML?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder

Does anyone know of a decent guide to create a UI without MXML?

I royally dislike mxml for programming and would like to go any other way possible. (Pure Actionscript or Flash Professional for UI)

Comment: Are you looking to use the Flex UI components from with AS3, or other ways to make UI in a general sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Flash Builder to edit the Actionscript part of a Flash Pro project. There's a huge discussion about techniques with example files and everything [here](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4836121#4836121).

Comment: Matching your method with this thread: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/864992 gets me where I need to go.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Flex and never write any MXML. However, you may find that becomes counter productive. I create views/skins declaratively in MXML and do everything else in Actionscript.

Creating views, populating them with child objects, adding listeners, setting styles, all of this is done in a few simple lines of MXML. Doing the same tasks with Actionscript statements means a lot more typing. The MXML code is more concise, and that gives it a lot more clarity/maintainability in my opinion:

MXML:

```
<s:Group width="100%">
    <s:Button label="button" click="onButtonClick()" paddingTop="0"/>
</s:Group>
```

AS3:

```
var g:Group = new Group();
g.percentWidth = 100;
var b:Button = new Buton();
b.label = "button";
b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
b.setStyle("paddingTop", 0);
g.addChild(b);
```

I often create custom components (that I re-use in app views) in pure AS3. I implement the Flex life cycle methods, and then composite these components into an MXML view.

I do prefer to write everything in pure Actionscript. The one place I will not do it, however, is in creating views/skins for my applications. I think it's a fair trade off.

Comment: Agree completely with this and dana's comment.  Flex is basically short hand and allows you to write something in an XML style which is easier to read in terms of relationships between objects (take HTML as another example).  Sure you can build the whole display tree in javascript, but then understanding that code is a mess.  I prefer functional things (like for loops) stay in my script blocks and layout based stuff and most visual things remain in the MXML (unless it's a very specific visual component that needs to be custom coded).